# Customize validator for spring validation framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have a `Application Level Service` below:

```
@Service
public class DatasetApplicationService {

  private DatasetRepository datasetRepository;

  @Autowired
  public DatasetApplicationService(DatasetRepository datasetRepository) {
    this.datasetRepository = datasetRepository;
  }

  @Transactional
  public Dataset createDataset(@Valid CreateDatasetCommand newDatasetParams) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Look at the method `DatasetApplicationService.createDataset`, a parameter `CreateDatasetCommand` is sent to it with an annotation `@Valid`. The annotation can be triggered to validate the `CreateDatasetCommand` when the method is called (see [spring boot bean validation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation)).

My question is Can I give a customized validator for specific parameter. For example I have a `CreateDatasetCommandValidator` which implements `org.springframework.validation.Validator` I wanna trigger this validator before the method is called.

---

I do some research with `InitBinder` but it seems not triggered during the process, the **FAILED EXAMPLE** is:

```
@Service
public class DatasetApplicationService {

  private DatasetRepository datasetRepository;
  private CreateDatasetCommandValidator validator;

  @InitBinder // <----- this is not triggered
  protected void initBinder(DataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);
  }

  @Autowired
  public DatasetApplicationService(DatasetRepository datasetRepository,
                                   CreateDatasetCommandValidator validator) {
    this.datasetRepository = datasetRepository;
    this.validator = validator;
  }

  @Transactional
  public Dataset createDataset(@Valid CreateDatasetCommand newDatasetParams) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every request that is received by Controller, the @InitBinder method will be called, in order to avoid calling for every request we define value inside it.

```
@InitBinder(value="user")
public void anyName(WebDataBinder binder){
binder.xxx()
}
```

- Autowiring of the validator.
- Adding of the validator to the InitBinder.
- Apply @Valid annotation to the model in the concrete controller.